# App crashes when opening a site in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to open a url "http://../member.php?q=8" in my android application in background but i am not able to do it.

```
public class OpenUrlBackground extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                responseString = out.toString();
                out.close();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

The above is my AsyncTask usage and whenever i do:`new OpenUrlBackground().execute("the above link")`, my app crashes and the above url doesn't get opened in background.
Please help

Comment: Doesn't look like PHP; maybe Java?

Comment: please pst error log.

Comment: what is your error in logcat? and by the way `ord.apache library` is deprecated therefore `HttpClient` is deprecated. You should start using `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: com.example.sarthak.app1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.sarthak.app1, PID: 22295
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()